# Accessing layout components on fragments in activity?

Tags: java, android

I changed my activity_main.xml layout in three tabs using fragments. I want access to all my tab components in MainActivity, like I did before, but I get NullPointersException. What I am doing wrong here. Thanks!

My fragment code:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class FragMent3 extends Fragment {

    EditText textBox;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.logbook_view, null);

        return view;
    }   
}
```

Code for third layout tab:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Send request"
        android:onClick="onSendButtonClicked" />

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Write request.."
        android:ems="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Parts of MainActivity code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TabListener {
    RelativeLayout rl;


    EditText textBox;
    static int x;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        try {
            rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

            fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
            bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Info").setTabListener(this));
            bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Pilot").setTabListener(this));
            bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Logbook").setTabListener(this));

            bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
            bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            bar.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        /**
         * Hiding Action Bar
         */
    }

    FragMent1 fram1;
    FragmentTransaction fragMentTra = null;
    FragMent2 fram2;
    FragMent3 fram3;


    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if (tab.getText().equals("Info")) {
            try {
                rl.removeAllViews();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            fram1 = new FragMent1();
            fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
            fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram1);
            fragMentTra.commit();
        } else if (tab.getText().equals("Pilot")) {
            try {
                rl.removeAllViews();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            fram2 = new FragMent2();
            fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
            fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram2);
            fragMentTra.commit();
        } else if (tab.getText().equals("Logbook")) {
            try {
                rl.removeAllViews();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            fram3 = new FragMent3();
            fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
            fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram3);
            fragMentTra.commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    public void onSendButtonClicked(View view) {

        textBox.setText("some text on third tab EditText");
    }
```

LogCat:

```
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3103)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3098)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    ... 11 more
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    at com.example.colibri2bbui.MainActivity.onSendButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:201)
05-06 12:42:19.993: E/AndroidRuntime(29991):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: add your fragments to `FrameLayout`, not `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @Android-Developer that doesn't explain a NPE, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing your 'TAB' implementation is totally wrong. First of all, you should use `FrameLayout` as parent view to add/replace your `Fragments`. Second thing is that the logic in `onTabSelected` should be changed. Here is an example which is the proper way to use Tab Navigation in ActionBar.

First create your main.xml, where your Fragments will be added/attached :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Second you can create your tabs and add `TabListener` to them :

```
mMyActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

ActionBar.Tab mFirstTab = mMyActionBar.newTab();
mFirstTab.setText("First Tab");
mFirstTab.setTabListener(this);
mMyActionBar.addTab(mFirstTab);

ActionBar.Tab mSecondTab = mMyActionBar.newTab();
mSecondTab.setText("Second Tab");
mSecondTab.setTabListener(this);
mMyActionBar.addTab(mSecondTab);

ActionBar.Tab mThirdTab = mMyActionBar.newTab();
mThirdTab.setText("Third Tab");
mThirdTab.setTabListener(this);
mMyActionBar.addTab(mThirdTab);
```

and create your TabListener like this :

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // Check if the fragment is already initialized
    if (mFirstTab == null) {
        // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
        mFirstTab = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFirstTab, mTag);
    } else {
        // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
        ft.attach(mFirstTab);
    }
}

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (mFirstTab != null) {
        // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
        ft.detach(mFirstTab);
    }
}

public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
}
```

And about `NullPointerException` in your code, as I can see your `EditText` : `textBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);` which you are trying to use in your `MainActivity` is declared in your third's tab layout. This `EditText` should be declared and used in your `FragMent3`, not in `MainActivity` .

Hope this answer help you!

Comment: Thanks, but I have problems with impelemnting your code. I get a lot of errors. What about this example? http://getquery.com/android-fragment-tab-example/ it's very simple and works. Btw, I want manage all tab components in MainActivity not in fragment class, is this wrong?

Comment: No, you can manage your tabs in Activity too and about the code, you just need to do it in your way, I am just pointing you how to achieve this. The code depends much on the way you are creating your Fragments and how you are instantiating them. About the example which you gave me, it's using `TabHost`, not ActionBar Tabs. So it depends which tabs you want to use, ActionBar or TabHost?

Comment: I just need three tabs in my app, each tab will have some UI components, which I will update them from MainActivity. When I started to read about tabs, I read that TabActivity is now deprecated, so I need substitute for that. But with my lack of knowledge of object programming I'm litlle bit lost in a lot of examples and tutorials on net. TabHost is not deprecated, right? Thanks for help!

Comment: To use TabHost, you have to use TabActivity which is deprecated, that's why in the example you send they are using FragmentTabHost. If you want this kind of tabs go and use the code from your example, if not the approach which you have to follow is the code I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: You can delete this line

```
textBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

And just use the View passed as argument in your `onSendButtonClicke` method:

```
public void onSendButtonClicked(View view) {

    ((EditText)view).setText("some text on third tab EditText");
}
```

Comment: I have RelativeLayout in activity_main..<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: @anze87 I updated my answer again, take a look to see if it helps you.

Comment: Do I need to define EditText in fragment? Because now I get error: Multiple markers at this line
 - TextBox cannot be resolved 
  to a type
 - TextBox cannot be resolved 
  to a type

Comment: My fault, sorry, I just invented a new class called TextBox xD It's a normal EditText.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the EditText is defined in the fragment's layout file. In this case you can't access it directly by `findViewById` but you need to get the fragment's view and then call `view.findViewById`

Comment: I want to use setText and getText methods in MainActivity for EditText which is placed on fragment layout. onClick methods for buttons works in MainActivity, but when I tried to success EditText from MainActivity, crashes. I think that definition is not correct. I tried to define it like u said, but it still doesn't work..